# Select primary keys from list of entities, generic (using ObjectContext)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

In another question on stackoverflow I found that one can find the primary key VALUE of an entity of  type T  with

```
x=> x.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value
```

I have an IQueryable < T >  q

*where TModel : EntityObject,new()*

and I want to get a list of all primary keys.

```
   List<int> primarykeyvalues =  q.Select(x => (int)x.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value).ToList()
```

**ArrayIndex is not supported by LINQ to Entities**

This should in essence do the same as

```
List<int> primarykeyvalues = DB.Products.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList()
```

(but then generic)

*(I realise that this is only for non-composite keys, but that's irrelevant in my case)*

**Any way to work around linq-to-entities not recognizing EntityKeyValues's array indexer?**

Solution HAS to be generic, and i'd rather not depend on something like "Id" in a magic string. Completely Alternative ways to get the all these primary key values are ofcourse lways welcome.

Comment: e.Select(x => x.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.First().Value).ToList() ?

Comment: That just throws an error saying I cant use EntityKey...

I have temporarly solved it by using dynamic linq and doing something similar to 

IQueryable<int> qint = (IQueryable<int>)q.Select("it.Id"); and then tolisting that , dirty as hell, i'm still open for a more built-in solution